# QT question about how to use a pointer to MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I know how to use a pointer to Widget like  `Widget* fatherPtr = (Widget*)parentWidget();`.

But in MainWindow it doesn't work when I use `MainWindow* ptr = (MainWindow*)parentWidget();`. It seem that it's an invalid pointer. How to solve it? I am anxious to get the correct solution, thank you very much!

Comment: What does your widget hierarchy look like? on which widget are you calling `parentWidget`? Also, widgets should only very rarely need to contact their parent directly, normally the parent sets up everything for the child by means of properties and signal-slot connections.

Comment: https://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/get-mainwindow-qt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved my question by using the function declared in MainWindow:

```
MainWindow* MainWindow::getMainWindow()
{
    foreach(QWidget *w, qApp->topLevelWidgets())
    if (MainWindow* mainWin = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(w))
            return mainWin;
    return nullptr;
}
```

Thank you to everyone who helped me

Comment: Just a note. If you are interested in the mainwindow that a specific widget is the child of, you can use `window()` method which returns the top-level widget. So `auto mainWin = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(window()))` (instead of `parentWidget()`). This way you don't have to iterate through top-level widgets.